# Can't install LibGDX [Build Tools 27.0.2]

Tags: android, error-handling, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

i installed LibGDX on my PC and created an Project. 
But when i open it and try to build it a error appears:
Install Build Tools 27.02 and sync project!
[image: Error]

when i click on it, it says cant find build tools 27.02 and when i check for it in the settings i cant find it either. 
the list ends at number 26!
[image: List of Build Tools]

Does somebody know this problem?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: updated my post hope that is the right build.gradle

Comment: `buildTools` last version is `26.0.2`. change to it and try to sync project

Answer (score 0):

change the version in build.gradle **(was 27.02)**

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 25
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your `build.gradle` app:

```
repositories {
// If you're using a version of Gradle newer than 4.1

// google()

// If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1
 maven {
     url 'https://maven.google.com'
 }
}

dependencies{
...
}
```